# Eclipse- How to remove jars which are added "from class path" of referenced library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-classpath

I use eclipse. I just added two jars into my project as library >Add external jar . As in below picture, all other jars in the folder are coming to my project as referenced library. How to remove this. Are these really required ? After I compiled, the app jar file size is much bigger than I expected.

[image]

tool tip shows-`from class path of .jar`

[image]

Comment: Usually, jars don't magically appear. Are they part of a project template? Or are you extending a project someone started before? Or (maybe) did you use some kind of dependency management?

Comment: I started this as a new project. I haven't myself used any other dependency management.

Comment: I checked my .classpath file. I can see only the jar file path which i added. by project template, you mean .project file ?

Comment: @Rilwan did you solve this problem ? if yes pls provide answer!

Comment: @sunleo: No man, I tried several things, i don't remember it got fixed. Then I moved to `Idea intellij` - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Answer (score 8):

**To remove a library reference from the project classpath, follow this procedure:**

1.Right-click on the project in the **Project Explorer** view and select **Properties** from the drop-down menu.This will open the **Propertis** dialog.

2.On the Propertis dialog, select the **Java Build Path** from the list of properties.

3.On the **Java Build Path** part of the dialog, select the **Libraries** tab.

4.Find the entry in the list of libraries called Shared Library [], and then select it.

5.Click **Remove**.

Comment: thanks, but all jars are not appearing in project properties. uploaded another image.

Comment: There is no "Shared Library []" here

Answer (score 5):

Right click on project, goto Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then goto the Libraries Tab, select the Referenced library and click remove.

Comment: thanks, but all jars are not appearing in project properties. uploaded another image.

Comment: There is "Referenced Library" in that dialog, although I have libraries imported "from Class-Path" of another library

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to remove those other `.jar` files was to move them into another directory.

In my case, I had a `lib/foo-deps` directory from which I needed two small .jar files out of about a dozen huge `.jar` files.  This made `Ctrl+Shft+T` Open Type take almost a minute.  So, I made a `lib/foo-runtime-deps` directory and put everything I did not need to compile into that directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Right click on your project and select options as mentioned in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATEW0.jpg)

[Select libraries and remove jars that you don't require](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQSe9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Select Project in Project Explorer and Press "Alt+Enter" then Go to Java Build path and select Libraries then select jar file finally click on Remove button.

Or Another way is their

select jar in the Project tree-view and right click on it and select Build Path then in select the Remove from Build Path . You are done.